# Valor total de una matriz

Tags: python, ejecutar

Hola pueden ayudarme a calcular el valor total de una matriz lo que llevo del codigo es lo siguiente

```
matriz=[]

fila=int(input("Ingrese cantidad de fila en la matriz: "))
columna=int(input("Ingrese cantidad de columna en la matriz: "))

for i in range(fila):
    matriz.append([0]*columna)

for i in range(fila):
    for j in range(columna):
      matriz[i][j]=int(input("Matriz {}, {}: " .format(i,j)))
    

print(matriz)
print(""" """)
```

el siguiente me calcula lo que es la fila y columna

```
for i in range (fila):
  totalf=sum(matriz[i])
  print("Suma Fila {}:".format(i),totalf)


for j in range (columna):
   totalc=sum(fila [j] for fila in matriz)
   print("Suma Columna {}:".format(j),totalc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sacar el total de la matriz solo basta con sumar todas la filas o solo las columnas, si sacas la suma de filas y luego columnas estás sacando el mismo total.

Así quedaría tu código:

```
total=0
for i in range (fila):
  totalf=sum(matriz[i])
  total += totalf
  print("Suma Fila {}:".format(i),totalf)

#imprime el total de la suma de todas las filas
print(total)
```